# Interpreting interaction term that only includes some of the variables in the model

Tags: regression, interaction, interpretation, multinomial-distribution

I have a multinomial regression model with 5 variables (forced to enter the model), and all 2 way interactions between those variables (forward stepwise). The variables are: age, education level, income, gender, and household size. When I ran the model, only one interaction term was added to the final model (being significant). My question is can I center those variables that were in the only significant interaction term and re-run the mode to facilitate the interpretation of the coefficient? All examples I saw say that one you can center variables but were for examples like: X+Y+XY.  I totally understand this, but my case is different: X+Y+Z+XY, instead. How can I interpret this coefficient? the graph way seems to be useless
Attached is the outcome of the regression
[image]

Comment: what is  "Z"  in your equation and what is its semantic ?

Comment: I added the regression model to the question above.

Comment: May describe variables X, Y etc and  computation procdure for Z in the model. Indicate Depedent variable.

Comment: Xs: education level, age , income, household size gender, and 2-ways interaction among all variables. 
I honestly dont understand what you means by computation procedure for Z. I used SPSS multinominal NOMREG using "NumCurOther_Class" as the dependent variable , which means current vehicle class owned, defined as : 1: others (reference), 2: full size , 3: SUV.

Comment: would you explain X+Y+Z +XY model you are trying to implement.

Comment: what is your data and the objective of your study?